# Writing Exif Data to Amazon S3 Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, exif

I'm having trouble writing exif data to my images on upload to Amazon S3. The code below encodes the file type to jpg format, rewrites the exif data and saves it to amazon s3. Although the images are saved successfully to Amazon S3, when I download the images and read the images via an ExifData viewer, I can't find the newly written exif data.

What is the best way to write exif data to my images on upload via laravel amazon s3?

> 

```
    $image = Image::make($file)->encode('jpg');
    

    //Image Upload
    Storage::disk('s3')->put($new_name, $image->stream()->__toString(), [
    
        // HTTP Headers
        'Expires' => 'Thu, 12 Feb 2032 08:24:43 GMT',
        'Tagging' => 'hello',
    
        // Metadata or other S3 options
        'MetadataDirective' => 'REPLACE',
        'Metadata' => [
            'name' => 'test',
            'Custom-Key' => 'test',
        ],
        'Exif' => [
            'DateTimeOriginal' => new \DateTime(),
            'Artist' => 'Your Name',
            'Copyright' => 'Copyright 2023 by Your Name',
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: _"The code below encodes the file type to jpg format, rewrites the exif data"_ - have you verified that part actually worked, _before_ the upload to S3?